# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un .exe a traves de un endpoint alojado en mi servidor IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

Tengo una pagina asp que genera tickets y tengo otra donde creo los endpoint para mi aplicacion principal. Cree una aplicacion en la consola que envia correos de forma automatica y quiero hacer una conexion con mis 3 aplicaciones.

Mi problema es que cuando llamo a mi endpoint usando postman y depuro sale que ejecuta bien las cosas pero el proceso de llamar a mi archivo .exe no lo corre correctamente.

Incluso intente hacer que abra una carpeta especifica en el servidor al llamar al endpoint, pero nuevamente hace el recorrido me devuelve estatus 200, pero esas actividades no las realiza.

No se si es porque IIS no me deja ejecutar esos procesos, le intente dar permisos para hacerlo pero no logre hasta el momento entender si eso es posible.

Comment: El exe debe tener permisos de ejecución con el usuario de IIS

Comment: ¿Has revisado lo que dicen los `logs`?